# Selecting correct carton based on qty

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create a function that will select the correct carton based on the qty of the carton content.

Here are my cartons that have the number of items they can hold:

> ```
> SMALL_PASCAL = 300
> BIG_PASCAL = 600
> BABY_BOX = 1200
> A485_1201 = 1800
> A4140_1901 = 3000
> A485 = 5000
> ```

And here is the method that will return the `CartonType`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Carton Type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="qty"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[Test]
private static CartonType GetCartonType(int qty)
{
     if (qty <= 300)
     {
         return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
     }
     else if (qty > 300 && qty <= 600)
     {
         return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
     }
     else if (qty > 600 && qty <= 1200)
     {
         return CartonType.BABY_BOX;
     }
     else if (qty > 1200 && qty <= 1800)
     {
         return CartonType.A485_1201;
     }
     else if (qty >1800 && qty <=3000)
     {
         return CartonType.A4140_1901;
     }
     else // 5000 or more.
     {
         return CartonType.A485;
     }
}
```

Calling the method like so:

```
int qty = 1540;
Console.WriteLine(GetCartonType(qty));
```

Output:

```
A485_1201
```

Is there a better way to achieve this rather than an `if` statement? Also, I just had a thought that what if the qty is like 10,000? I would then require 2 A485.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to achieve this rather than an If statement?

Yes. You could have an enumeration of the container types and their capacities, in increasing order by capacity,
loop over in order,
and as soon as you find one that's big enough, return it.

It's perhaps easier to see after you simplify the if-else chain,
by removing redundant conditions, for example:

```
 if (qty <= 300)
 {
     return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
 }
 if (qty <= 600)
 {
     return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
 }
 if (qty <= 1200)
 {
     return CartonType.BABY_BOX;
 }
 // ...
```

Comment: do you have any suggestion if there is for anything over 5000? so eg the largest box and a small pascal could be required?

Comment: @user1234433222 sure, but we don't implement feature requests here... You could subtract from the quantity the capacity of the selected container, and then call the method again.

Comment: Thanks for that, working backwards might be the key to this.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bug

There is a bug in your example where you are using `SMALL_PASCAL` twice:

> ```
>  if (qty <= 300)
>  {
>      return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
>  }
>  else if (qty > 300 && qty <= 600)
>  {
>      return CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL;
>  }
> ```

---

#### More flexibility with *free* mappings

I would take a different approach for the other answer. Quantities are something that might change in time or be different in different contexts so I wouldn't use them as `enum` or `const` values but instead created a *pure* `enum` first:

```
public enum CartonType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    SMALL_PASCAL,
    BIG_PASCAL,
    BABY_BOX,
    A485_1201,
    A4140_1901,
    A485,
    Default = A485
}
```

where there are two new items: `Undefined` and `Default` - that we can conveniently use in a new extension method. It would map `Quantity` to `CartonType` for any collection:

```
public static CartonType GetCartonType(this int quantity, IEnumerable<(int Quantity, CartonType Type)> mappings)
{
     var mapping = mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => quantity <= m.Quantity);
     return 
        mapping.Type == CartonType.Undefined 
            ? CartonType.Default 
            : mapping.Type;
}
```

With this you can specify different quantities if necessary and use them as a parameter:

```
var quantityCartonTypeMappings = new(int Quantity, CartonType Type)[]
{
    (300, CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL),
    (600, CartonType.BIG_PASCAL),
};

var quantity = 700;

var cartonType = quantity.GetCartonType(quantityCartonTypeMappings);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big fan of "smart" `enum` because they do not scale well (what if you will have a more complex logic?) and they force you to spread business logic all around in your code. Because of this - in most cases - I'd suggest to use the approach in [t3chb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/209812/13424) ("mapping" might be even moved to a separate configuration/rule file).

For simple cases you have, however, an easier approach:

```
enum CartonType
{
    SMALL_PASCAL = 300,
    BIG_PASCAL = 600,
    BABY_BOX = 1200,
    A485_1201 = 1800,
    A4140_1901 = 3000,
    A485 = 5000,
}

CartonType GetCartonType(int quantity)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(CartonType))
        .Cast<CartonType?>()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .LastorDefault(x => quantity <= (int)x) ?? CartonType.A485;
}
```

I don't like that `CartonType.A485` hard-coded default then you might need to make it slightly more complex:

```
CartonType GetCartonType(int quantity)
{
    var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CartonType));
    var biggest = types.Cast<CartonType>().Max();

    return types
        .Cast<CartonType?>()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .LastOrDefault(x => quantity <= (int)x) ?? biggest;
}
```

Simply used like this:

```
Debug.Assert(GetCartonQuantity(100) == CartonType.SMALL_PASCAL);
Debug.Assert(GetCartonQuantity(1000) == CartonType.BABY_BOX);
Debug.Assert(GetCartonQuantity(10000) == CartonType.A485);
```

**Note**: if you put this "business knowledge" inside your `enum` then you must write proper tests not only for `GetCartonQuantity()` but also for `CartonType` itself (to be sure values are consistent).